# Windows Phone MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged

Tags: c#, xna, media-player, windows-phone-7.1

I am writing a Windows Phone app that connects to the current media player (presumably Zune - not sure if anything else can even fill this role) to retrieve the current artist and song name for additional use. When the app first loads I have a view that shows this information, however when I change tracks it doesn't update. I've tried attaching to the MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged event, but it never seems to fire both in the code-behind or in my ViewModel (using MVVM Light). To confirm this, I put a MessageBox.Show in the event handlers in both places and neither ever show up.

Here is a code example:

```
public MainViewViewModel()
{            
    MediaPlayer.ActiveSongChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(MediaPlayer_ActiveSongChanged);
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles a song change so the view is updated.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
void MediaPlayer_ActiveSongChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    MessageBox.Show("song changed");
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here? The event handling seemed rather basic so I'm not sure what I'm missing. The above code (with/without the FrameworkDispatcher.Update()) was tried in both the code-behind and a VM and neither work.

Also, is there any way to test this without having to deploy to my device every time? The emulator doesn't seem to detect that Zune is running/playing on my system so I have to deploy whenever I try something new.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this event is called not globally, but locally. They mean changing active song is that you use MediaPlayer inside your application.
Let me illustrate:

```
 private void PlayNextSong()
    {

      Song song = Song.FromUri(activesong.Name, new Uri("test" + i.ToString() + ".mp3", UriKind.Relative));
      MediaPlayer.Play(song);
      i++;
      FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      PlayNewSong();
    }
```

So if you'll run this code with yours event will be fired.

Comment: I was only trying to read the current song, not have any controls for playback. I think I'll go to a background thread that just polls the current song every few seconds or so and if it changes update accordingly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the [`BackgroundAudioPlayer.PlayStateChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer.playstatechanged%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) event instead.

Comment: No luck there unfortunately. I attached to the event and just set it up to do a MessageBox whenever the state change, but it never fired. From what I keep reading it seems like both of these apply to music being played by other sources (especially BackgroundAudioPlayer), but I'm only trying to get the information from Zune. I don't have any playback controls in my app nor do I intend to.

Answer (score 0):

XNA Framework events are triggered after calling

```
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
```

so it's convenient to create IApplicationService class with timer, that calls FrameworkDispatcher.Update() over and over again.

For more info and how to read this:
[Enable XNA Framework Events in Windows Phone Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff842408.aspx)